# Postgresql 14 Logical Replication

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-14, wal, logical-replication

I have set up a logical replication between Aurora Postgresql to AWS RDS Postgresql which was running fine to a certain point and got stuck.

I disabled and dropped the publication and subscriber slot. Created new slots, after that subscriber is reading from previous checkpoint(LSN).

I want to understand the behaviour that even after dropping the slots and recreating why it still reading from previous checkpoint(LSN).

I understand that subscriber stores the checkpoint and after restarts it reads from previous LSN but in my case I dropped and recreated both.

How can i make it to do a snapshot copy from beginning?

Comment: You cannot drop a checkpoint...

Comment: What I meant is I dropped the publication and replication slot and recreated.